# Display image on right side

Tags: html, css

We have page looking like [this link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/)

[image]

We want to display like below image :

[image]

1)reduce the background-color length of text `see cases`

2)Display Image on right side

I can try chnaging `position : relative; top: left: some px;` for everything. but i felt its bad coding. so please help for me.

**css**

```
.custom_case
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 95px;
}

.cc1
{
color: #ff7704; 
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size:34px;
}

.cc2
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:34px;

}


#brand_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}



#model_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;


}

.cc3 
{   
    background: #ff7704;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;   
}


.cc5
{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="custom_case">
    <div class="custom_case_left">
        <h1 class="cc1">Custom Cases</h1>
        <h2 class="cc2">Make Your Own design</h2>
    </div>

    <?php

    $brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';

    echo '<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';

    ?>

    <div class ="cc3">
    <div class ="cc4">
    <a href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html"><span class ="cc5"> See Cases </span> </a>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="custom_case_right">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/gal.PNG'); ?>" >


        </div>
```

Comment: Where is Your Html code?

Comment: use `float: right` property on image.

Comment: float: right; or display:inline-block; you are using Ul li like display:inline-block;

Comment: @IvinRaj i updated question with  code html

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe remaing html code?

Comment: @IvinRaj updated with all html code of page

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe thanks wait few minutes sir

Comment: agree with KalpeshSingh and IvinRaj - float: right / display: inline-block is your best bet

Comment: @KalpeshSingh please help for other points also

Comment: .custom_case_right img{
  float: right;
  
  }

Comment: @TT120 please help for other points also

Comment: @HarshadHirapara please help for other points also

Comment: There is one more thing in the code which needs some attention. You need to close the  `.custom_care_left` div right before `<div class='custom_care_right'>` but looks like you closed it after ` <h2 class="cc2">Make Your Own design</h2>`

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe see my demo

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe there is no other points - it's pretty much just float: right / display: inline-block, the only other thing is to do 50% width per div inside a parent div with 100% width

Comment: @Tympaaz Thanks for support.

Comment: @HarshadHirapara Thanks for support.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
 .custom_case
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 95px;

}
.custom_case_left h1
{
  font-size:20px;
}
.custom_case_left h2
{
  font-size:20px;
}
.cc1
{
color: #ff7704; 
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size:34px;
}

.cc2
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:34px;

}

.cc4
{
  width:200px;
}
#brand_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}



#model_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;


}

.cc3 
{   
    background: #ff7704;
    position:relative;
    top:20px; 
    width: 148px;
}


.cc5
{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}

.custom_case_right img {
    float: right;
    top: -150px;
    position: relative;
    right: -90px;
    width:250px;
}
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/sq8ak9kL/3/)

Comment: please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/) , image is displaying very less size

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe adjust Your image size

Comment: i want to display Make your own design text to liitle more left , so that exactly as like in 2nd image in question..

Comment: please help me to display space after `My brand` text. please check all 5 points in question

Comment: please help me to display space after My brand text in dropdown box

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe check it now

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe my Pleasure sir

Answer (score 2):

You can add this css property to your code

```css
.custom_case_right img{
  float: right;
  }
```

Comment: its displaying right side,  please help for other points also

Comment: i want to display `Make your own design` text to exactly between the `custom cases` text

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.custom_case_right {
    float: right;
    top: -200px;
    position: relative;
    right: -90px;
}
```

and add to .custom_case this:

```
height:550px;
```